# Porting audio from web browser to DAW

Tags: daw

I would like to port my audio from flash videos playing in Chrome or Firefox to FL Studio so I can use the EQ and Compressor on the audio. Is this possible?

Comment: Closed. This question is merely about extracting audio from flash applets rather than importing it in your DAW.

Comment: ...No it's not. I want to port the live audio through my DAW. not record it.

Comment: In any case, you can use VLC to extract the audio.  http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1266-extracting-the-sound-from-a-video-with-vlc

Comment: I still don't think you understand. I don't want to /extract/ the audio. I want to run a video in VLC with FL Studio open and port the audio though FL Studio from VLC so I can use the EQ and compressor effects in FL Studio on the audio from VLC

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get audio from flash videos.
The easiest way is to play the video in any browser while using your favorite recording software to record your sound cards output. Keep your volume levels near to the maximum (of course while not clipping). The channel you need to record will be named "Stereo Mix", "Wave out", "Monitor mixer" or something similar. Just look for changes in the recording software's peak meter while the video is playing if you can't find the right channel to record. Edit the audio, save to wav and you're done.

This will result in some loss of quality, though, but it might not be an issue when we're talking about flash-videos. You can also download the video and split the video and audio track (which is likely mp3) and convert it into .wav. The quality will be somewhat better, especially when dealing with cheap integrated audio chips which add a lot of noise while recording. You might also want to try to contact the author of the video and ask if he has and could give you the uncompressed audio track.